# Why is my Switchboard integration not being called?

Tags: smooch

I have a Switchboard and Switchboard Integration for Zendesk and a Switchboard Integration with a webhook.

When I look at my Switchboard using `GET https://api.smooch.io/v2/apps/{appId}/switchboards/` I see the `defaultSwitchboardIntegrationId` is my custom Switchboard Integration.

When I start a conversation, my custom Switchboard Integration is not activated, though. I can pass control to it with `POST https://api.smooch.io/v2/apps/{appId}/conversations/{conversationId}/passControl` and it fires at that point.

Why isn't it being activated by default if it's the `defaultSwitchboardIntegrationId`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a net-new conversation, it *should* begin with the `defaultSwitchboardIntegrationId`.

One way to know would be to inspect your app's `/logs` page in the Dashboard and see which integration received the event (it may have gone to Zendesk, a previous `switchboardIntegration`)

When testing the `defaultSwitchboardIntegrationId`, you can delete the user object via API to ensure that you get a fresh user+conversation.